# How to, from static methods ; access a unique value of a static property used in a static method

Tags: c#, class, methods, static

I want to access the value of a **static field** in other **static methods** running on the **same thread**. An example is in the code below :

The first class in this script is `ClassA`. ClassA's job is to compare two `Rect` value , If there is inequality between tho two compared `Rect` values then a public boolean is set to true;

in classA , `IsRectChanged` is a bool method which takes a parameter object of type `Rect` and compares it to  `StoredRect` which is a `Rect`. The method returns true when `storedRect` and the `Rect` value of `IsRectChanged` do not match.

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        private Rect storedRect;

        public ClassA() { }

        public bool IsRectChanged(Rect rect)
        {
            bool isChanged = !rect.Equals(storedRect);
            if(isChanged)
            {
                storedRect = rect;
            }

            return isChanged;
        }
    }
```

This is `ClassB` 
We create a static field of `ClassA` named `isRectChanged` in `ClassB`.
Do not change the structure of the `MethodB` in ClassB. Consider the fact that 50 other methods in static and non static classes must use a `ClassA` field . Needing to change the structure of `ClassB` in order to make the code work is would be counterproductive.

```
    public static class ClassB
    {
        private static ClassA RectHelper = new ClassA();

        public static void MethodB(Rect yourRect)
        {
           if(RectHelper.IsRectChanged(yourRect))
           {
               Debug.Log("Changes were made");
           }
        }
    }
```

`ClassC`, `ClassD` and `ClassE` are running on the same thread.They both call `ClassB.MethodB` and assign a `new Rect` in the parameter of `MethodB`.

Because `ClassC` ,`ClassD` and `ClassE` are call `ClassB.MethodB` and assign a `new Rect` in the parameter of `MethodB`. They each override the `storedRect` value of the static field `ClassA RectHelper`.

Because of this ,`ClassA` `RectHelper.IsRectChanged` will always be true.

How do I work around this without having to  make `ClassB`'s `ClassA`'s and `ClassE`'s `MethodB`  non static ?**

```
    public class ClassC
    {
        public void UpdateEverFrame()
        {
            ClassB.MethodB(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
        }
    }
    public class ClassD
    {
        public void UpdateEverFrame()
        {
            ClassB.MethodB(new Rect(100, 100, 10, 10));
        }
    }
```

Here in `ClassE` `ClassB.MthodB` is called in two `UpdateEverFrame` methods , one of which takes in a int parameter . They override each other if they are called simultaneously, so the system will believe that `IsRectChanged` is true and  will always return true. which is a big problem.

We dont want `IsRectChanged` to be overridden , We want each Call of `ClassB.MethodB` to be treated as if it are not static so that `IsRectChanged` is never overridden

```
    public class ClassE
    {
        public void UpdateEverFrame()
        {
            ClassB.MethodB(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
        }

        public void UpdateEverFrame(int i)
        {
            ClassB.MethodB(new Rect(100, 100, 10, 10));
        }
    }
```

In my question When I say 'access a unique value of a static property' I am talking about `ClassB.RectHelper`.

I know that `ClassB.RectHelper` is STATIC so the value will be shared between the classes `ClassC`, `ClassD` and ClassE, whenever they call `MethodB`. But can we work around this so that `ClassC` and `ClassD` so not override the `storedRect` value in ClassA ?

Comment: Please give a better description of what you want to do.  Consider providing some code to show what you are getting in contrast to what you want to get.

Comment: I changed the question and added more information , 
see ClassE and the description above

Comment: Still not helpful for us to help you.  Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the purpose but have you thinked about making `ClassB` generic? Something like that:

```
    public class ClassB<T>
    {
        private static ClassA if_rect_Changed = new ClassA();

        public static void MethodB(Rect yourRect)
        {
            if (if_rect_Changed.RectChanged(yourRect))
            {
                Debug.Log("Changes were made");
            }
        }

    }
```

And use it like it: `ClassB<ClassC>.MethodB(rect)` so every class will have it's 'copy' of 'change tracker' and you will be able to keep `MethodB` static.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just skip the static class B and just make a static property of your class A in your classes C and D. The way you've structured the code seems messed up to me. Another way I would deal with this is to do something like :

```
public class ClassA
{
    protected Rect storedRect;

    public ClassA() { }

    public virtual void UpdateEverFrame();

    protected bool IsRectChanged(Rect rect)
    {
        bool isChanged = !rect.Equals(StoredRect);
        if(isChanged)
        {
            storedRect = rect;
        }

        return isChanged;
    }
}

public class ClassC : ClassA
{
    public override void UpdateEverFrame()
    {
        if(IsRectChanged(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)))
        {
             Debug.Log("Changes were made class C");
        }
    }
}
public class ClassD : ClassA
{
    public override void UpdateEverFrame()
    {
        if(IsRectChanged(new Rect(100, 100, 10, 10)))
        {
             Debug.Log("Changes were made class D");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if ClassD used void `Update`  and not  `UpdateEverFrame` I would need to add a vertual method to `ClassA` the code would become too rough . Making whatever class Iwant to use ClassA inherit ClassA makes everything less flexible

Comment: you can remove the UpdateEverFrame function from the ClassA and inherit only the storedRect and IsRectChanged functions and then implement whatever functionality you need in your child classes. All your classes use the storedRect and IsRectChanged so its logical to use ClassA as base class rather than static instance that every other object would override.

Answer (score 0):

First some clarifications. I am assuming you are using System.Windows.Rect, correct?  More clarifications...

> We have a static property for ClassA in ClassB called **isRectChanged**

No, you have a static field of type ClassA in ClassB called **RectHelper**.  **IsRectChanged** is a non-static method of ClassA.

> We want to access the value of a **static property** in other **static methods** running on the **same thread**.

Since they are on the **same thread**, you have no chance of your static method being called simultaneously.  So far, no problem.

> They both call **ClassB.MethodB** and override the value of **MethodB's Rect parmeter**.  Both classes use the same instance of `ClassB.MethodB` ...

They do not **override** the **Rect** parameter, instead they each supply a **Rect** object.  **ClassB** is the instance, not `ClassB.MethodB`.

> ...will always be true.

**That is not so**, try running the code below and you will see that only the first call returns **true**.

```
ClassC c = new ClassC();
c.UpdateEverFrame();
c.UpdateEverFrame();
c.UpdateEverFrame();
```

But if you insert calls through **ClassD** between the lines, yes, `IsRectChanged` will return **true** because it is true, the **Rect** is in fact different.  But, that is what **static** is for, i.e., it's for **Singleton** type operations.

If you want a **per class** static variable, then put a static variable into each class.  If that would require you to duplicate code, then use a *template*.  It doesn't have to be fancy, for instance, simply change **ClassB** and the calls to **ClassB**'s methods as follows...

```
public class ClassB<TClass> // the rest of the class is the same
...
/* in ClassC */ ClassB<ClassC>.MethodB(new Rect(...));
...
/* in ClassD */ ClassB<ClassD>.MethodB(new Rect(...));
```

By making **ClassB** into a template, each ClassB<> is a different static object each with its own copy of static variables.  Now, the following code will return **false** for all but the first call on **ClassC** and **ClassD**.

```
        ClassC c = new ClassC();
        c.UpdateEverFrame();
        c.UpdateEverFrame();
        c.UpdateEverFrame();
        ClassD d = new ClassD();
        d.UpdateEverFrame();
        d.UpdateEverFrame();
        c.UpdateEverFrame();
        d.UpdateEverFrame();
```

Here are the classes...

```
public static class ClassB<TClass>
{
    private static ClassA RectHelper = new ClassA();

    public static void MethodB(Rect yourRect)
    {
        if (RectHelper.IsRectChanged(yourRect))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Changes were made");
        }
    }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public void UpdateEverFrame()
    {
        ClassB<ClassC>.MethodB(new Rect(0, 0, 20, 20));
    }
}
public class ClassD
{
    public void UpdateEverFrame()
    {
        ClassB<ClassD>.MethodB(new Rect(100, 100, 10, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I updated my question to be more specific and detailed . I made correction where i had property where field should be .

I am unable to change the structure of ClassB ouside of changing the way `ClassB`'s `RectHelper`  field is structured

Comment: If you could change ClassB to a template, would that solve your problem?  When I read your question, I still am not sure I understand your request.

Comment: `CassA`'s bool  `IsRectChanged()` when given a `Rect` parameter will check to see if the `Rect` parameter is equal to  `storedRect` if not `IsRectChanged` is set to true. Letting the the user know that "oh look the rect values dont match, something changed"

Now , we dont need it to be a `Rect` , it can just be an `object`.

Now , `ClassB` makes use of ClassA  as `RectHelper` . if at any time In `ClassB`  ,`MethodB`'s  Rect param `yourRect` does not match  `ClassA.storedRect` i.e (RectHelper.storedRect) this will be printed out to the user `("Changes were made"); `