# How do I prevent the simultaneous usage of a static field by the static methods that use it?

Tags: c#, methods, static, field

okay hi  Here is a quick and straight to the point example of the problem.

```
public class MyTestClass
{

    private static float FloatField;

    public static float MethodA( float yourFloat)
    {
        FloatField = yourFloat / 10 * 0.125f;
        return FloatField;
    }

    public void SomeOther_Non_Static_Method()
    {

    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    float FloatA;
    void Running()
    {
     FloatA =  MyTestClass.MethodA(1.2f);

    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    float FloatB;
    void Running()
    {
        FloatB = MyTestClass.MethodA(8.4f);

    }
}
```

As you can tell , `FloatField` will be assigned a value by `MyTestClass.MethodA` in `ClassA` and `ClassB` simultaneously. Thus overriding the values set be either.

I want it so that no overiding takes place .

Couple things to point out . The float Method in `MyTestClass` must **remain** static. The structure of `MethodA` in `MyTestClass` must remain unchanged

I don't want to believe that his is the end of the line and that doing this is completely impossible right now . I think that there must be a way . If you have any ideas please share.

Comment: if you cant or dont want to change `MethodA` still you can use @dasblinkenlight solution. use lock inside methods running. `lock(obj){ FloatB = MyTestClass.MethodA(8.4f); }` while `obj` is an object inside MyTestClass. use lock for another method running too just like this note that they must share the `obj`. dont use different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways around it:

- **Introduce a local variable, use it in computations, and set the value at the end** - this would let you compute the right result in both methods, because each one will get its own storage for the result, or
- **Use locking** - this would make concurrent computations wait for each other to finish, preventing simultaneous writes to `FloatField`.

Here is the first approach:

```
public static float MethodA( float yourFloat) {
    var temp = yourFloat / 10 * 0.125f;
    FloatField = temp;
    return temp;
}
```

Here is the second approach:

```
private static Object floatFieldLock = new Object();

public static float MethodA( float yourFloat) {
    lock (floatFieldLock) {
        FloatField = yourFloat / 10 * 0.125f;
        return FloatField;
    }
}
```

Both approaches are going to solve the problem of returning a wrong result when `MethodA` is called concurrently. Neither approach is going to solve the inherent race condition, in that the end value of `FloatField` will be set to the last value that happens to write to it, which is an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
I would like to use locking but I thought that locking was to be used when we are dealing with multi-threading.

Comment: Okay this would work . I will use the first approach. I cant get lock to work.
I have another similar issue that i have not been able to solve.
this is the question. [my Similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772062/how-to-from-static-methods-access-a-unique-value-of-a-static-property-used-in)

I would be grateful if you could help me there too